# Elasticsearch - filter and sort by name with Priority exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm trying to filter and sort by name with **Priority exceptions**, which means that even if the results is sorted alphabetically I want a specific name to appear first.

For example - this is my base query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 500,
  "min_score": 0.15,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "brand.id"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "brand.names.1.raw": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

In short, I want this array ["pepsi" , "rc-cola", "coca-cola"] to be sorted by giving **top priority** to "rc-cola" so that it will be sorted as ["rc-cola", "coca-cola", "pepsi"]

Right now it sorts alphabetically.
I thought about a few ideas that could work:

1. Add a "should" with boosting by "match". but then I had problem with
   sort by "_score", it breaks my alphabeticaly sorting, although I first sort by "_score" and by the brand name. example with adding this to the "bool": "should":[{"match":{"brand.id":{"query":34709,"boost":20}}}
2. I tried with "aggregates" so that the first query (bucket) would be
   "match" the specific brand name and sorts alphabeticaly inside, the
   second query would sorts alphabeticaly only. but I totally messed up.

I have to use filtered -> filters, I can't use scripts queries. 
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Here is an example of documents and how it is sorted right now. 
I want the "ccc" brand to be prioritized first, please help me update my query.

```
{
  "_index": "retailer1",
  "_type": "product",
  "_id": "1",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "id": 1,
    "brand": {
      "names": {
        "1": "aaa"
      },
      "id": 405
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "aaa"
  ]
},
{
  "_index": "retailer1",
  "_type": "product",
  "_id": "2",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "id": 2,
    "brand": {
      "names": {
        "1": "bbb"
      },
      "id": 406
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "bbb"
  ]
},
{
  "_index": "retailer1",
  "_type": "product",
  "_id": "3",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "id": 3,
    "brand": {
      "names": {
        "1": "ccc"
      },
      "id": 407
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "ccc"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Following. I also tried to do the same without scripts.

Comment: What is that array? You want brands to be sorted on you priority or what?

Comment: If you post document example and expected result it would help to understand

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat - post updated

Comment: Could you indicate the version of Elasticsearch you're using? I believe it's relevant to the options available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using Elasticsearch version 1.x, following query should provide you with the expected result:
(might have to adapt a bit to use raw fields if needed)

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "brand.names.1": "ccc",
                "boost": 10
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "brand.id"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "brand.id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "brand.names.1": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

On later versions of Elasticsearch [The filtered query is replaced by the bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/query-dsl-filtered-query.html),
this query should do the job (with similar adaptation as previous one for use of raw fields if needed)

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "brand.id"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "brand.names.1": "ccc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    {
      "brand.names.1": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In both cases, you can make use of the boost function if you want to have the top filled with more than one preferred match, in a given order

Comment: if we need the order like ["ccc","aaa","bbb","ddd","eee","ffff"],what would be the possible adjustment made to the query if the prioritized records need not to sorted asc or desc?

Answer (score 4):

I have tested localy here it is. Also to simplify query ask NOT for name but for brand IDS since your brand could have many names. If you still wish to do sort on names then you can modify script as you wish

```
POST stack/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "brand.id"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "params": {
            "ids": [
              406,
              405
            ]
          },
          "inline": "return params.ids.indexOf(doc['brand.id'].value) > -1 ? 1000 - params.ids.indexOf(doc['brand.id'].value) : _score;"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but as I told: "I must use filtered -> filters, I can't use scripts queries."

Answer (score 3):

If the priority of brand is known at index time, then you can directly index it in your doc like :

```
"brand": {
      "name": "ccc",
      "priority":1000,
      "id": 407
    }
```

The brands to be shown on top can have a high popularity value, whereas the rest can have a popularity value assigned to a lower value.

By indexing it this way, you can directly sort it by using `brand.popularity` as the primary sort and `brand.names` as the secondary sort

```
"sort" : [
        { "brand.priority" : {"order" : "desc"}},
        { "brand.name" : {"order" : "asc" }}
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to be depends on the indexing

Comment: Did you mean any brand can have different priority for different queries?

Comment: No, I know I can do it in the index, I don't want to make it depends on the index.. I have a few bushiness reasons. I'm looking for other options. thanks

Comment: At query time, how are you going to pass the relative priority of brands given the fact that it may not be known apriori which brands are going to match with your filter criteria. The overall brand list may also grow enormously.

Comment: thats exactly what I asking, I want to boost the brands with the priority and make sure that the other brands will still be sorted alphabetically

Comment: My point is : If you are planning to pass the priority of brands at query time provided you don't even know the applicable brands matching the filter criteria, that seems totally impractical to me unless that information is stored somewhere in the index.

Comment: but I know the brands that I want to be prioritize at the query time, see my example